# Local Schedule Notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, alarmmanager, localnotification

I want to trigger a local Notification daily on a specific time(Chosen by user). Similar to alarm type. With the help of date picker. User must select the days and time, it should push a local Notification on that time daily.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have already preset **`flutter_local_notification`**

you can go ahead and do it as follows

`DateTime scheduledTime` handles date time allocation

```
 import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart'as notifs;
    Future<void> scheduleNotification(
        {notifs.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifsPlugin,
        String id,
        String title,
        String body,
        DateTime scheduledTime}) async {
      var androidSpecifics = notifs.AndroidNotificationDetails(
        id, // This specifies the ID of the Notification
        'Scheduled notification', // This specifies the name of the notification channel
        'A scheduled notification', //This specifies the description of the channel
        icon: 'icon',
      );
      var iOSSpecifics = notifs.IOSNotificationDetails();
      var platformChannelSpecifics = notifs.NotificationDetails(
          androidSpecifics, iOSSpecifics);
      await notifsPlugin.schedule(0, title, "Scheduled notification",
          scheduledTime, platformChannelSpecifics); // This literally schedules the notification
}
```

> How will user choose the date(for how many days local notification should be triggered daily on a specific time

you can use datetime picker to select date if its a one occurrence notification

if it has to occur on different days same time , you can use a [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) and run every 24 hrs and end the services after no of frequencies are over

check this [blog post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/background-local-notifications-in-flutter/)

Comment: you can read more here https://medium.com/@fuzzymemory/adding-scheduled-notifications-in-your-flutter-application-19be1f82ade8

Comment: How will user choose the date(for how many days local notification should be triggered daily on a specific time)? I don't want it hardcoded. User must select the days with datepicker or something.